# Property does not exist on type 'never' in Ngrx effect

Tags: ngrx-effects, angular8

I'm using Angular 8 and NGRX 8. I have an action:

```
export const loadEnvironment = createAction(
  LicencingActionTypes.LoadEnvironment,
  props<{environment: Environment}>()
);
```

and corresponding effect:

```
 loadEnvironment = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LicencingActionTypes.LoadEnvironment),
    exhaustMap((action) =>
      this.authService.
      getToken(LicencingEffects.getAuthDetailsForEnvironment(action.environment))
        .pipe(
          switchMap((token) => [
            AuthActions.onLogin({token: token}),
            LicencingActions.onLoadEnvironment({environment: action.environment})
          ]),
          catchError(error => of(AuthActions.onLoginError({error: error})))
        )
    )
  ));
```

I've been reading the documentation on NGRX 8 (https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#incorporating-state).

Their example shows that you can just use the action property without casting the type of the action:

```
...
exhaustMap(action =>
        this.authService.login(action.credentials)
...
```

Webpack won't compile, and I get the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/licencing/effects/licencing.effects.ts(20,69): error TS2339: Property 'environment' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

[Screenshot of code with errors highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMrxS.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actions must be declared in a type union at the bottom of the actions file:

```js
const all = union({
  info,
  appError
});

export type CoreActionsUnion = typeof all;
```

and then in the Effects class constructor injected in with that type as the type parameter of Actions:

```js
constructor(private actions$: Actions<CoreActionsUnion>) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the Enum of the action, just pass the function instead. At least it works for me. (Angular 14.x, TS 4.7 and NgrxEffects 13.x, RxJS 7.5.x )

This is what my code looks like where I'm updating a spare part

```
readonly updatePart$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(updatePart),
      concatMap(action =>
        this.partService
          .updatePart(action.part)
```

Action itself

```
export const updatePart = createAction(
  PartActions.update,
  props<{ part: Required<Part> }>()
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your `effect` as below -

```
loadEnvironment = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(loadEnvironment), //<-- this is your action
    exhaustMap(action => //<-- getting rid of extra parenthesis
      this.authService.
      getToken(LicencingEffects.getAuthDetailsForEnvironment(action.environment))
        .pipe(
          switchMap((token) => [
            AuthActions.onLogin({token: token}),
            LicencingActions.onLoadEnvironment({environment: action.environment})
          ]),
          catchError(error => of(AuthActions.onLoginError({error: error})))
        )
    )
  ));
```

Sample reference [implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdlunc)